# Generic maven runner Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use ${PROJECT.DIR} on the project path (working directory) of the maven runner on the intellij configuration but its not working. Does the intellij idea has some sort mechanism like ${project_path} on eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that working directory accepts variables (at least, I can't make it work that way). Why don't you use a fixed directory, and point it at a symlink to achieve something similar?

Comment: Would not help if you have a dozen of projects (at least i dont see how)